# Why all of my CPUs scale to the max freqency when only one of them is runing at 100% and all the others at around 0%?

Tags: linux, cpufreq

I am running Ubuntu 18 on a System76 Oryx Pro 4 with an i7 8th gen 6 cores.

Here is the output of `lscpu` for your reference:

```
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              12
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-11
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  6
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               158
Model name:          Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz
Stepping:            10
CPU MHz:             1268.451
CPU max MHz:         4100.0000
CPU min MHz:         800.0000
BogoMIPS:            4416.00
Virtualisation:      VT-x
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            256K
L3 cache:            9216K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-11
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp flush_l1d
```

As you can see from the following image, when all CPUs usage is <= 6%, all CPUs run at a frequency of 800MHz.
[image]

However, when I run the following command in a terminal, which causes CPU5 usage to ramp up to 100%, all CPUs (even those with 0% usage) scale to 4,100 MHz which is the maximum CPU freq.

```
while :; do :; done
```

[image]

Is this the expected behavior?

Also, is there any way that the behavior can be changed so that only the frequency of the CPU with 100% usage increases to the top speed?

Comment: When you say you have a loop happening in the terminal, how?  Bash script? Something else? What if you run the loop with `&` appended to it and then attempt to run the script as a new process?

Comment: Can you tell us exactly which CPU you have?

Comment: I have update the question description with the information required

Comment: @JakeGould I have added the command that I have used to the description. If run the loop with `&` I observe exactly the same behaviour